# Define theme colors in Tailwind with CSS variables

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to define background colors in tailwind config file with CSS variables and fallbacks from the predefined colors.

So this is what I'm trying:

```
green: {
    DEFAULT: 'rgb(var(--user-color-green, ' + colors.green[500] + ') / <alpha-value>)',
}
```

This does not appear to work since the "colors.green[500]" value will be in a hex format. The result looks like this:

```
.tw-bg-green {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(#22c55e / 1);
}
```

But if I define the color like this:

```
green: colors.green[500],
```

The color value will be in hsl format? See below:

```
.tw-bg-green {
    --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(34 197 94 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
```

How can I define the background colors with CSS variables and use fallback colors from the predefined Tailwind colors?